# Problems in default Android web browser

Tags: support, android

I'm having several issues using the site with the default android web browser. 
First, the notification bar doesn't stay at the top of the page, and tends to float on top of what you're doing.
Second, I can't seem to submit the search box on the main page, so, sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce either of your problems with Dolphin HD v4.1.0 on Android 2.2.1, using the Swype keyboard to submit searches. Maybe you should add more details of your environment, like software versions and what notification bar you're talking about.

Comment: I asked about searching on the [Android Enthusiasts SE](http://android.stackexchange.com): [How to use the Search box on these Stack Exchange sites with the Galaxy S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1872/98).  It may be fixed in Android 2.2 and higher.

Comment: I have an HTC Android 2.1. Just using the built in web browser. I mean the stack overflow notification bar. The one that says if you have new badges or whatever.

Comment: the "Welcome to" notification bar works fine for me (stays on top of the page and scrolls out of the visible area when scrolling down).

Comment: I also have an HTC that ran Android 2.1 when I bought it and now runs 2.2. I haven't seen these issues you describe in either version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, apparently you want to upgrade to Android 2.2 or higher?

Comment: 2.1 is what came with my phone and is all that is available from my carrier. I'm sure I can download a Rom and upgrade if I get the time. Oh well, its your site, if upgrading is the answer I guess that's all I can do.